# SSRS 2008 huge pdf report, blank pages

Tags: pdf, reporting-services

We are having an issue while generating a huge PDF Report. We are using SSRS 2008 and a particular report generates more than 1000 pages. If I export to PDF format, the data is populated upto page no. 465 and rest of the pages till 1000 are totally blank. I have Adobe Reader 9.0 installed on my machine and I thought there should be some issue with the reader itself. I upgraded to Adobe Reader 10 but experiencing same issue. Everytime I generate the report and export to PDF (using the report viewer webcontrol), the pages become blank after 465. There is absolutely no problem with the data (the stored procedure which I am using to load customers) and I have verified in the backend. We had this issue last month and somehow it got fixed automagically. Now again we have the same issue. Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there was nothing wrong with SSRS or Adobe reader or anything related to caching. Some of the sections in each page were pushed to next page due to increase in height of an image. When I readjusted the height of the embedded image control, everything went fine.